# CreateConsoleScreenBuffer in Python

Tags: python, console, console-application, windows-console

I wrote a 3D game with Python to run in a console. To stop it from flickering, I have to write what I want to display to a `ConsoleScreenBuffer`. The documentation is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createconsolescreenbuffer). I know I have to use:

```
import win32console
buffer = win32console.CreateConsoleScreenBuffer()
```

but what are the parameters for the `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer()`? In the documentation it says:

```
HANDLE WINAPI CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
  _In_             DWORD                dwDesiredAccess,
  _In_             DWORD                dwShareMode,
  _In_opt_   const SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *lpSecurityAttributes,
  _In_             DWORD                dwFlags,
  _Reserved_       LPVOID               lpScreenBufferData
);
```

That's in C. `help(win32console.CreateConsoleScreenBuffer)` does not give useful information. The first 2 parameters are ints, the second a "PySECURITY_ATTRIBUTES"-object an the third is also an int. (I think?)

```
CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(DesiredAccess, ShareMode, SecurityAttributes, Flags)
```

```
DesiredAccess=GENERIC_READ and GENERIC_WRITE : int
GENERIC_READ and/or GENERIC_WRITE
ShareMode=FILE_SHARE_READ and FILE_SHARE_WRITE : int
FILE_SHARE_READ and/or FILE_SHARE_WRITE
SecurityAttributes=None : PySECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
Specifies security descriptor and inheritance for handle
Flags=CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER : int
CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER is currently only valid flag
```

I didn't find any examples of this being implemented online.

If you know any other methods of making a console draw faster, please tell.

This is my (not jet) game. It flickers, because its not drawn quick enough. The tutorial I was following is in c++ and uses CreateConsoleScreenBuffer to eliminate the flickering, because with it everything is drawn at once and not
successively.

```
import os
import time
import math
import threading


hardMap = [
    ["#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#","#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#","#","#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#","#"],
        ["#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"],

      ]


gameMap = "".join(["".join(hardMap[n]) for n in range(len(hardMap))])

notDone = True

rotationSpeed = 0.02

playerX = 5
playerY = 5
playerA = 0

fov = 4
fov = math.pi / fov

depth = 20

fps = 30

screenWidth = 120
screenHeight = 40
os.system(f'mode con: cols={screenWidth} lines={screenHeight}')

screen = [" " for n in range(screenHeight * screenWidth)]
mapWidth = len(hardMap[0])
mapHeight = len(hardMap)



def printScreen(string):
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(0.01)
    for x in [string[i:i+screenWidth] for i in range(0,len(string),screenWidth)]:
        print("".join(x))
    
c = 0
while(notDone):
    c += 1
    playerA = playerA + rotationSpeed
    startTime = time.time()
    
    for x in range(screenWidth):
        rayAngle = (playerA - fov / 2) + ((x / screenWidth) * fov)
        distanceToWall = 0
        hitWall = False
        shade = " "
        
        eyeX = math.sin(rayAngle)
        eyeY = math.cos(rayAngle)

        """
        with open("log.txt","a") as f:
            f.write("x"+str(eyeX)+"\n")
            f.write("y"+str(eyeY)+"\n")
            f.write("h"+str(mapHeight)+"\n")
            f.write("w"+str(mapWidth)+"\n")
            f.write("\n")
        """
        
        while not hitWall and distanceToWall < depth:
            distanceToWall = distanceToWall + 0.1
 
            testX = int(playerX + eyeX * distanceToWall)
            testY = int(playerY + eyeY * distanceToWall)

            if testX < 0 or testX >= mapWidth or testY < 0 or testY>= mapHeight:
                hitWall = True
                distanceToWall = depth
                 
            elif gameMap[testY * mapWidth + testX] == "#":    
                    hitWall = True
                
                
        ceiling = int((screenHeight / 2.0) - (screenHeight / distanceToWall))
        floor = screenHeight - ceiling  

        for y in range(screenHeight):

    
            

            
            if y < ceiling:
                screen[y * ceiling + x] = " "
            elif y > ceiling and y <= floor:
                
                if distanceToWall <= depth / 4: shade = u"\u2588"
                elif distanceToWall < depth / 3: shade = u"\u2593"
                elif distanceToWall < depth / 2: shade = u"\u2592"
                elif distanceToWall < depth / 1: shade = u"\u2591"
                else: shade = " "
        
                screen[y * screenWidth + x] = shade
                
            else:

                b = 1.0 - ((y - screenHeight / 2.0) / (screenHeight/2))

                if b < 0.25: shade = "#"
                elif b < 0.5: shade = "X"
                elif b < 0.75: shade = "."
                elif b < 0.9: shade = "-"
                else: shade = " "
                
                screen[y * screenWidth + x] = shade
                
    printScreen(screen)
    """
    with open("log.txt","a") as f:
            f.write(str("\n".join(screen)))
            f.write("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
    """
    time.sleep(max(1./fps - (time.time() - startTime), 0))
```

Comment: Do you have a simple example of its use (from Python)? If so, please add it to your question.

Comment: The flickering example is all I know of. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am assuming you are following javid/OLC's Console FPS tutorial.*

The simple answer is: you need `win32con` along with `win32console`, a better answer is below.

A little late but this page: [win32console docs @ Tim Golden](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32console.html) and [PyConsoleScreenBuffer Object @ Tim Golden](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyConsoleScreenBuffer.html) were very useful to figuring this out. There are two ways of doing this. One is using `win32console and win32con` and the other is to use ANSI Escape Sequences. Effectively, all you are trying to do is move the cursor to/print at 0,0 on the console. Here is method one:

```
import win32console, win32con, time
myConsole = win32console.CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(DesiredAccess = win32con.GENERIC_READ | win32con.GENERIC_WRITE, ShareMode=0, SecurityAttributes=None, Flags=1) # create screen buffer
myConsole.SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer() # set this buffer to be active
myConsole.WriteConsole("Hello World!") # Effectively the print func.
myConsole.WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(Characters="Hello World!\0", WriteCoord=win32console.PyCOORDType(5,5)) # Print at coordinates

time.sleep(3) # this must be called or you won't see results. This is because after running the code (because there is no loop) the cmd.exe takes the console over.
```

This should work fine in your console FPS (using WriteConsoleOutputCharacter). Just place the commands where javid places them and this should work fine. The second method is to use colorama/ANSI Sequences to return the cursor to the home position. This method can be summed up in: `os.system("echo \033[0;0H")`. You cannot use the escape sequences using the `print` function, they are not supported (except using *colorama*). Here is an example:

```
from colorama import init
from os import system
init() # I bother with this because I use colors too. Echo prints slower than print, so don't use echo if you can avoid it.

# ... game
# ... generate string to print
print(frame) # or just use you method of printing each line.
system("echo \033[0;0H") # return cursor to home position, ready for next frame.
```

I hope this helps! - Sky